# How to enable death notices in console of CS 1.6?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

Recently I noticed that the death notices are not shown in my console. Normally, you see which bot/player killed which bot. But here it is only showing radio messages, and not death notices.

I guess something has changed but I don't know what.

Is there any command which can disable it and can be enabled again?

[image]

Comment: Please only tag the game you're asking about. If this is about CS:CZ, then you don't need both tags.

Comment: @Wrigglenite there's *literally* no difference between these two. If someone has played CS 1.6 and has encountered this problem, he would definitely be able to solve this issue too. But if a person has played only CS:CZ, chances are he's a *noob* and less chances of solving the issue.

Comment: I can't look it up right now, because I'm only on my phone... what are mp_logecho and mp_logdetail set to? That'd be my first guess.

Comment: @dly mp_logecho  was 1, mp_logdetail was empty. So I set it to 1 and it made no difference. Still not getting death notices.

Comment: @Vikas try mp_logdetail 3, which should then catch everything. If that doesn't help I'll try to look for a solution when I'm back home.

Comment: @dly nothing changed. But one thing that you may want to know. After making it 1 or 3, I noticed these messages: 
No masters loaded
Using default master
Vikas attacked a teammate
Teammate kills: 1 of 3
Vikas attacked a teammate. I guess I didn't notice them before.

Comment: Ok, so the log levels are fine. I guess it's something related to the console itself. the log details determine what's being logged and output. One more thing: what's happening in your server log file (if there is one)?

Comment: @dly how to check that?

Comment: It should be in your cstrike directory under /logs/ or directly in it. I can be opened with a simple text editor.

Comment: mp_logfile is 1. But there are no logs folder in cstrike. And not even a file named log.

Comment: I've just tried with a clean installation + bots mod and it did it right away. All kills were shown properly. Could you please attach the config file you used?

Comment: @dly solved :D Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is 3rd time I posted a question and myself found the solution by *mistake*. Actually I pressed <kbd>I</kbd> while playing by mistake and it turned on the death notices in console. By default, GUI interactive tutor was enabled.

But I don't know why when this is enabled console doesn't show death notices.

Comment: Wow, that's a weird behavior of the game.

Comment: You may want to try it if you have czero game?